# Как ввести значение через одну программу в другую? python

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть 3 файла первый это файл .txt  с тестами из которого мы должны брать значения при помощи третьей программы  и подставлять их в файл номер 2 с кодом и  выходные данные должны отправляться в файл 3, у меня получается их забирать, но как их отправить в файл 2 через файл 3(файл 2 и 3 это .py а 1 .txt
Как через core.py ввести в n=int(input()) в student.py тест из tests.txt
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, тут можно использовать [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html):
В вашем случае, [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

```py
from subprocess import run, PIPE

inputStr = 'Demo input to process...' # Как-то получается из tests.txt

solution = run(['python', 'student.py'], stdout=PIPE,
               input=inputStr, encoding='ascii') # Запускаем файл

print(solution.stdout) # solution.stdout - вывод student.py
```

"Почти что" перевод [этого ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163542/how-do-i-pass-a-string-into-subprocess-popen-using-the-stdin-argument) на Русский.

Answer (score 0):

Для простого и ясного примера будем проверять возведение чисел от 1 до 100 во вторую степень. Тот функционал программы, который мы будем проверять должен быть выполнен, например, в виде функции `main`.

Файл `teacher.py`:

```
def main(s):
    return int(s)**2
```

Файл `student.py`:

```
def main(s):
    n = int(s)
    result = n * n
    return result
```

В файле `tests.txt` указаны числа от 1 до 100, по одному на каждую строку:

```
1
2
3
4
...
98
99
100
```

И, наконец, файл `score.py`:

```
teacher import main
student import main

with open('tests.txt') as f:
    tests = f.read().split()
    
teacher_res = [teacher.main(i) for i in tests]
try:
    student_res = [student.main(i) for i in tests]
except:
    print('В процессе выполнения программы ученика произошла ошибка')

student_right = 0
for i in range(len(teacher_res)):
    if teacher_res[i] == student_res[i]:
        student_right += 1
        
result = student_right/len(teacher_res)*100
print(f'При проверке совпало {result}% ответов')
```

Это, конечно, не единственно верное решение. Его можно улучшить, например, добавив индикатор выполнения теста при помощи модуля `tqdm` или любого другого, можно сделать вывод результата в отдельный файл или даже выводить туда тесты, на которых произошла ошибка, можно выполнить эту же задачу совсем по-другому, например переписав всё в ООП стиле. Я считаю, что это решение одно из самых простых и его может быть достаточно.

Comment: В тесте ученика не может быть функций, поэтому её нельзя импортировать.